# Elixir Gulp BrowserSync seperate development server

Tags: laravel-5.3, gulp-watch, browser-sync, laravel-elixir

I am developing Laravel websites on a development server in my network.

My gulpfile.js

```
mix.browserSync({
    open: 'external',
    host: 'website1.devserver.tld',
    proxy: 'website1.devserver.tld',
    port: 3000,
    files: [
        'app/**/*',
        'public/**/*',
        'resources/views/**/*'
    ],
});
```

The result when starting gulp watch:

```
[BS] Proxying: http://website1.devserver.tld
[BS] Access URLs:
 -----------------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://website1.devserver.tld:3000
 -----------------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://website1.devserver.tld:3001
```

I've added NAT routes in my router to the webserver's IP for ports 3000 and 3001

I've added listen 3000 and listen 3001 to /etc/apache2/ports.conf (On Ubuntu 16.04)

I've added *:3000 en *:3001 to the Virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:3000 *:3001>
    ServerName website1.devserver.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website1
   <Directory /var/www/website1>
     AllowOverride all
     Require all granted
   </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I load my developent websites locally and externally through http://website1.devserver.tld

Still, BrowserSync is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Fannypack,](https://github.com/lukeed/fannypack) you will get a higher page return to the Elixir avoiding the delay of 1.5 seconds or more depending on your project. I'm not claiming that Fannypack is better than [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html), but it solves everything I found irritating about it.